# ASP.NEt MVC edit files on server after deploying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I deployed my site on IIS 7. Can I edit c# files after deploying? In my sites's directory I see only .cstml files (Views), but there are no c# files... How can I do some changes in code without full redeploying? Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is likely a Web Application project. In that project type, the code files are compiled into an assembly (.dll) and that assembly is deployed to the server (the code files are not).

There is another project type called a Web Site, and that one works more like what you are looking for. The code files are deployed with the application, and if you edit any of them, the changes are available immediately (i.e. the code is recompiled).

There are other differences between the two, so please read up on them and decide if it's the right path for you.

Personally, I haven't worked with the Web Site project type in years. Back when it was first released, there was a big outcry against it (so much so that MSFT released an update to restore the Web Application project type), but this is all opinionated and it may work great for you.

There's an [MDSN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx) that details the differences.

The intro paragraph tells you how to create a project of each type in Visual Studio.

Comment: If my response answers your questions, please mark it as the accepted answer (check mark to the left). Thanks!